# Interesting and hard definite integral question

Tags: calculus

> Find the maximum value of $t$ possible
>
> $$
> \int_{-1}^{t}\left[\,\sin\left(\,x^{3} - 9x^{2} + 18x\,\right) + x^{2} -6x +
> {11 \over 3}\,\right]\,\mathrm{d}x = 0
> $$

This question is rather hard in my opinion,  so I hope someone can help with this problem. Though I know the answer should be $7$, I don't really know how to come up with that.  I would greatly appreciate if anyone would be able to help me.

By the way,  when I try to type this integral into online integral calculators,  all they say are standard calculation time exceeded. I wonder if there is any simple workaround to solve these types of integrals. If yes,  maybe we can understand integration more?

Once again,  thank you for looking at this question,  and your possible efforts in solving it.

Comment: The problematic part here is that there is no way to express the integral of the function $$f(x)=\sin{\left(x^3-9x^2+18x\right)}$$ in elementary functions.

Comment: Yes, and this is the part where I was stuck.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Let $x = y+3$, the integral at hand can be rewritten as

$$\begin{align}
\mathcal{I}(t) 
&\stackrel{def}{=} \int_{-1}^t \left(\sin(x^3-9x^2+18) + x^2 - 6x + \frac{11}{3}\right) dx \\
&= \int_{-4}^{t-3} \left(\sin(y^3 - 9y) + y^2 - \frac{16}{3}\right)dy
\end{align}
$$
Notice $\sin(y^3-9y)$ is an odd function in $y$, we have

$$\mathcal{I}(7) = \int_{-4}^4 \left(\sin(y^3 - 9y) + y^2 - \frac{16}{3}\right)dy
= \int_{-4}^4 \left( y^2 - \frac{16}{3}\right)dy
= \left[ \frac{y^3 - 16y}{3} \right]_{-4}^4 = 0$$
For $t > 7$, we have
$$\frac{d\mathcal{I}(t)}{dt} = 
\left.\sin(y^3 - 9y) + y^2 - \frac{16}{3}\right|_{y=t-3}
\ge -1 + (t-3)^2 - \frac{16}{3} > 4^2 - \frac{19}{3} > 0$$
This means $\mathcal{I}(t)$ is strictly increasing on $[7,\infty)$
and $\mathcal{I}(t) > \mathcal{I}(7) = 0$ whenever $t > 7$.

As a result, $7$ is the largest $t$ where $\mathcal{I}(t) = 0$.